# Two Definitions of the Weyl Tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, definition, curvature

I'm reading "Textbook in Tensor Calculus and Differential Geometry" by Prasun Kumar Nayak and came across the Weyl tensor/projective curvature tensor $C_{kijl}$. The book states that
$$C_{kijl}=R_{kijl}+\frac{1}{1-N}(g_{kj}R_{il}-g_{kl}R_{ij}) \tag{1}$$

However I found on Wikipedia that
$$C_{iklm}=R_{iklm}+\frac{1}{N-2}(R_{im}g_{kl}-R_{il}g_{km}+R_{kl}g_{im}-R_{km}g_{il})+\frac{1}{(N-1)(N-2)}R(g_{il}g_{km}-g_{im}g_{kl})  \tag{2}$$

It was not immediately obvious to me that both of these are equivalent to each other?

Comment: It's not immedately obvious to me either, but the Ricci tensor and scalar are defined in terms of the Riemann tensor and the metric. Have you tried using these definitions in the second expression and working out the result?

Comment: Aren't the "(Weyl) projective curvature tensor" (1) and the "Weyl tensor" (2) different things altogether?

Comment: @Nihar Karve I can't find any Wiki articles for the projective curvature tensor, and the Weyl tensor is also called the Weyl curvature tensor (although no 'projective') so I assumed that they are the same? The textbook I'm reading calls it the Weyl Tensor as well.

Comment: @Toffomat I understand the conversion between Ricci and Riemann but It seems quite difficult to prove the equivalence

Comment: @Chern-Simons interesting, it appears to be defined the same way as eq (1) in https://ijpam.eu/contents/2017-113-3/5/5.pdf (where it explicitly called the projective curvature tensor). I must admit I've never seen the first definition anywhere, only the second.

Comment: ...I still think, however, that either these are two different objects, or the first equation only holds due to the symmetries of the spacetime under consideration

Comment: @Nihar Karve I think you're correct. From I gathered in MathSE is that $(1)$ is the Projective Weyl Curvature Tensor ($W_2$) $\neq $ Weyl Tensor http://repository.ias.ac.in/31209/1/31209.pdf